# FactoryGirl records are not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm trying to write tests, on which company objects are saved. But, company objects are not saved, and there is no company record on the table. Why and how can I fix the problem?

db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140626075006) do
  create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

app/models/company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

spec/factories/companies.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name "MyString"
  end
end
```

spec/models/company_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Company do
  let(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }
  context "test context"do
    it "test" do
      Company.first.name
    end
  end
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
end
```

result

```
/Users/machidahiroaki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/machidahiroaki/RubymineProjects/rspec_sample/bin/rake spec
Testing started at 19:48 ...
/Users/machidahiroaki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/bowling_spec.rb ./spec/models/company_spec.rb

NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
./spec/models/company_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2 examples, 1 failure, 1 passed

Finished in 0.090546 seconds
/Users/machidahiroaki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/bowling_spec.rb ./spec/models/company_spec.rb failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 18):

Ah, got burnt by this a couple of times.

`let` expressions are lazily evaluated. You didn't reference that one, so the `company` never got created. You can use `let!`, for example.

```
  let!(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }
```

Or reference that `company`

```
let(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }
context "test context"do
  it "test" do
    expect(company).to_not be_nil
    expect(Company.count).to eq 1
  end
end
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. However, when I put a break point on "expect(Company.count).to eq 1" and run it, there is no record on the companies table. why does it happen?

Comment: @HiroakiMachida: Since you `use_transactional_fixtures`, all specs run within a database transaction. The idea is that the transaction will not be committed and therefore rolled back at the end of an example. This behavior is faster than deleted all manually data from the database manually after the test suite run. Uncommitted transactions are not visible to other database connections, therefore the breakpoint cannot see the record.

Comment: This saved my butt, thank you